# Dealing with more complicated tree level feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Suppose I have a 2 -> 4 body process of the form

[image]

Where all particles are scalar $\phi$ of mass $m$, dirac fermion $\chi$ of mass $M$ with interaction lagrangian $g\overline{\chi}\chi \phi$ . How does one order the calculation correctly to compute this amplitude, given that there are the three propagators to consider here? does ordering matter in the toy case?

Comment: Well, in principle you just use the Feynman rules. If you're confused about how to use them, show us what you've tried.

Comment: So, by cutting the diagram into three components (two 2->2 scattering and the fermion propagator), $-iM =[ \bar{u}(q)gu(p_1) \Delta(p_1-q,m) \times \bar{u}(p_6)gu(p_2) ]\times S(q,M) \times[ \bar{u}(p_3)gu(q) \times \Delta(p_3-q,m) \times \bar{u}(p_4)gv(p_5)]$

Comment: You have 8 fermion wave functions but there are only 6 external legs